# WSO2 Developer Studio gives error however it works in production

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

So I have these two lines of code in a sequence in production. cb0token and cb-email are custom headers and it works great however there are a lot of other issues with the production environment so I am trying to make it compatible with the developer studio. I get tons of errors but I cannot for the life of me solve this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="UserSessionValidate" onError="ReturnError"   xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="token" expression="$trp:cb-token" />
    <property name="email" expression="$trp:cb-email" />
</sequence>
```

this however works. I just can't get expressions to work. I've tried other variables in the expression also but nothing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="UserSessionValidate" onError="ReturnError"   xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="token" value="value" scope="operation" type="STRING" description="token"/>
</sequence>
```

This code works in production however when trying to save the file in the developer studio (in eclipse) i get the following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: bundleresource://1009.fwk142638629:21/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.<init>(SynapseXPath.java:104)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.custom.CustomSynapsePathFactory.getSynapsePath(CustomSynapsePathFactory.java:44)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.PropertyMediatorTransformer.createPropertyMediator(PropertyMediatorTransformer.java:171)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.PropertyMediatorTransformer.transformWithinSequence(PropertyMediatorTransformer.java:74)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.AbstractEsbNodeTransformer.doTransformWithinSequence(AbstractEsbNodeTransformer.java:103)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.SequenceTransformer.transformWithinSequence(SequenceTransformer.java:75)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.DefaultEsbModelExporter.transformSequence(DefaultEsbModelExporter.java:179)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.internal.persistence.DefaultEsbModelExporter.designToSource(DefaultEsbModelExporter.java:324)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbObjectSourceEditor.update(EsbObjectSourceEditor.java:135)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.updateSourceEditor(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:548)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.handleSourceViewActivatedEvent(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:541)
at org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb.diagram.part.EsbMultiPageEditor.pageChange(EsbMultiPageEditor.java:499)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:292)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:778)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3080)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1772)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:279)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

session data

```
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

Comment: which WSO2 esb version you are using??

Comment: Both using 4.8.1 at the time. Honestly we just moved on and haven't touched the developer studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just worked through a similar issue.  It looks like you are trying to use Java 8, which seems to be unsupported (and broken).  Try uninstalling all Java versions and install only Java 7.

[WSO2 Developer Studio (3.7.1) error when using expression get-property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701229/wso2-developer-studio-3-7-1-error-when-using-expression-get-property)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to uninstall or reinstall Java. In `eclipse.ini` file you can set concrete jdk to use. Just add **-vm** parameter before `-vmargs`.

For example:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe    
-vmargs    
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6    
-Xms40m    
-Xmx512m
```